# Text string Localization for ASP.NET WEB API 2 Self-host application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return different msg for requests from different locale, below sample code is part of my `OAuth` **self host application** (.exe application) for grant credential for request with user name and password, for simplify, I hard coded the locale to `zh` which is chinese:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
        string culture = "zh";
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        Resources.Culture = ci;
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", Resources.UserNameOrPwdError_ErrorMsg);
            // omit other stuff....
}
```

And also, I've tried:

```
var testStr = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("UserNameOrPwdError_ErrorMsg", ci);
```

Both cases returned the **English** text.

BTW, I've added `system.web` section to my **App.config** (self host don't have web.config):

```
  <system.web>
        <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"></globalization>
  </system.web>
```

I'm not sure where to put the chinese text resource file since it's not a traditional ASP.NET project and don't have those **Special project folders**, so by looking the Project folder structure, I put a file besides the default existed one and added the translated key/value pair, I've set the `Access Modifer` to public:

[image]

tested with the rest client, the returned string is always english, anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I assume that `AuthService` is a class library.

Personally I'd put my resx files in a seperate folder called Resources or something along those lines.

In your code you can then just use the ResourceManager:

```
//Namespace.Folder.File.Resourcemanager
AuthService.Resources.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceKey", ci);
```

Make sure, that you have set your resx file access modifier to public. Default is internal.

If you want to add resources to an Asp.Net web application project, right click your project in the Solution Explorer, go to Add folder and add the `App_GlobalResources` folder. Put your resx files there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you!

Try to add below line in your web.config (system.web section)

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"></globalization>
```

You need to instantiate new Current Culture.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        string culture = "zh";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", Resources.UserNameOrPwdError_ErrorMsg);
    }
```

Comment: as per @Marco answer, moving resx file into App_GlobalResources  folder is advisable.